# Why the output strings concatenate in a weird way?

Tags: c, string, csv

I want to use my generic vector to hold the data from a line in the csv file. But I meet a problem. My input is:

> MonsterID,Name,Hitpoints,Attack,Defence,AttackTimes,Gold,Exp,Special

The output become

```
Field 0 would be MonsterIName
Field 1 would be Name
Field 2 would be HitpointAttack
Field 3 would be Attack
Field 4 would be Defence
Field 5 would be AttackTiGold
Field 6 would be Gold
Field 7 would be Exp
Field 8 would be Special
```

Here are the parts of the code relevant to this problem:

Definition of the `Vector` type:

```
typedef void (*VectorFreeFunction)(void *element);

typedef struct Vector {
    void *elements;   // An array of elements
    int capacity;     // The allocated size of the array
    int size;         // The number of elements in use
    size_t elemSize;  // Size of the data type of the element.
    VectorFreeFunction freeFunc;
} Vector;
```

**csv.c**

```
...
Vector *getfields(char *line) {
    int i = 0;
    const char *token;

    Vector *fields = vectorAlloc(sizeof(char*), NULL);

    for (token = strtok(line, ",");
         token && *token;
         token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"), i++)
    {
        vectorPush(fields, (const void*)token);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != fields->size; i++) {
        printf("Field %d would be %s\n", i, (const char*)vectorAt(fields, i));
    }

    return fields;
}
```

**vector.c**

```
Vector *vectorAlloc(size_t elemSize, VectorFreeFunction freeFunc) {
    Vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    if (vector == NULL) {
        fatalError("Cannot allocate vector");
    }

    vector->capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    vector->size = 0;
    vector->elemSize = elemSize;

    vector->elements = malloc(elemSize * vector->capacity);
    if (vector->elements == NULL) {
        fatalError("Cannot allocate elements array of the vector");
    }

    vector->freeFunc = freeFunc;
    return vector;
}

void *vectorAt(Vector *vector, int position) {
    assert(position < vector->size && position >= 0);
    return ((char*)vector->elements + (position * vector->elemSize));
}

void vectorPush(Vector *vector, const void *element) {

    if (vector->size == vector->capacity) {
        _vectorDoubleCapacity(vector);
    }

    void *destAddr = (char*)vector->elements + vector->size * vector->elemSize;
    memcpy(destAddr, element, vector->elemSize); // add to end of vector

    vector->size++;
}

void _vectorDoubleCapacity(Vector *vector) {
    vector->capacity *= 2;

    vector->elements = realloc(vector->elements, vector->elemSize * vector->capacity);
    if (vector->elements == NULL) {
        fatalError("Resizing the capacity of vector fails");
    }
}
```

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is too minimal, e.g. `Vector` definition is missing.

Comment: I don't use elemSize for two different things. But your comment about that I have problem with string bigger than 8 bytes is enlightening. I should check that now.

Comment: You only allocate `elemSize` bytes for each element, which seems to be 8. So you can only fit strings of 7 characters or less, plus terminating null character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you push onto the `Vector` are pointers into the array pointed to by the `line` argument to `getfields`. It is difficult to keep track of the lifespan of the `Vector` elements this way, you should instead allocate copies of the tokens with `strdup()` and pass `free` as a `VectorFreeFunction` when creating the `Vector`.

Futhermore, `vectorAt` returns a pointer to the vector element, which itself is a `char *`, the way you use it to print the contents of the `Vector` is incorrect: you should cast it as `(char **)` and dereference it.

Here is a corrected version:

```
Vector *getfields(char *line) {
    int i = 0;
    const char *token;

    Vector *fields = vectorAlloc(sizeof(char*), free);

    for (token = strtok(line, ",");
         token && *token;
         token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"), i++) {
        vectorPush(fields, strdup(token));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fields->size; i++) {
        printf("Field %d would be %s\n", i, *(char **)vectorAt(fields, i));
    }

    return fields;
}
```